# firebase how to get values from database (website)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get values 0 from firebase realtime database as variable in JavaScript. have easy way to get it? (I tried to find from this website but there is only have android).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must get a reference to where the data is stored.

```js
let ref = firebase.database().ref("database/path/to/limitedorder/Apoint");
```

Next, you must choose how you would like to be notified of data changes. For your use case, this would be subscribing to the `'value'` event only once. This will return a [Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) that resolves with the desired data.

```js
let valuePromise = ref.once('value');
```

You then need to chain to the promise to handle/manipulate the data returned by the server and/or handle any errors.

```js
valuePromise.then((dataSnapshot) => {
  let desiredValue = dataSnapshot.val();
  console.log("Desired value: ", desiredValue);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log("An error occurred:", error);
})
```

Bringing this altogether gives:

```js
firebase.database().ref("database/path/to/limitedorder/Apoint").once('value')
  .then((dataSnapshot) => {
    let desiredValue = dataSnapshot.val();

    console.log("Desired value: ", desiredValue);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("An error occurred:", error);
  })
```

Detailed explanation of these steps is provided in the [Firebase RTDB for Web documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once).